# High traffic, 500M+ hits per day (analytics like) application architecture on Azure

Tags: architecture, azure, analytics, azure-table-storage

This question is for experienced architects - How do the big boys do it? :)

**Overview**

I am building this high traffic, analytics like solution based on .NET, it ultimately will hosted on Azure. Let's assume this web app will receive 500M+ "transactions" every day, and these are very quick hits to our servers, very little DB querying for each will be required, virtually all of the heavy lifting will be done on a server side on set intervals. I am pretty sure that I have to implement some sort of a queue that will store all of the incoming hits and implement "aggregators" on a back-end that will run every minute or so to process new items from the queue.

**Suggested Solution**

Correct me if I am wrong but I am thinking writing these transactions straight to the database (some sort of the log table) would be a mistake, so I will be utilizing the Azure Storage Account (Table) for my queue and spin off couple of Azure Worker Roles (based on need) to process the data and update the database. Thoughts?

It's important to remember that Azure Storage is mostly based on a per-transation model, so I would have to pay for all incoming transations (writes) AND for the transactions for my aggregators (reads). So 500M writes and 500M reads per day, which comes out to be around $100/day. Does that make sense? Also, with using Azure Storage can I read a block of rows (to account for a single transaction) or I would have to read the queue one record at the time?

Lastly, performing a DB insert/update for each row would be an overkill for my aggregators, so I am thinking each one should probably aggregate the workload in memory and then purge it to the database.

Comment: looks more like Programmers question than SO, there isn't any particular programming question here

Comment: not a detailed answer, but somewhere to start; take a look at CQRS, DDD and RabbitMQ/Azure Service Bus. Then perhaps look at a nice light weight api like nancyfx hosted using http://bit.ly/1zRXQma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that requests to update the analytic data in storage should be done via messages dropped to queues so that worker roles can process those messages in the background w/o impacting live users.  You can even automatically scale your servers based on the amount of data in the queues by using something like AzureWatch @ http://www.paraleap.com

I would urge you to think about the fact that each queue can support up to 500 transactions per second.  If you will need more, consider hosting multiple queues and having a pattern to your queues (could be as simple as having X queues that can be connected to randomly: "Queue001..Queue100".  Worker Roles would be checking all 100 queues, while your web servers would be generating a random number between 1 and 100 and connecting to that queue

Amount of transactions might actually be much larger:
500M hits to your service per day prorbably means:

- 500M writes to queues
- 500M reads from queues
- n * 500M writes to storage (where n maybe a multipler, if your storage structure
  requires you to read things first before writing them out, allows
  batch transactions, etc.)
- x * 24*60*60/delay checks against queues to see if new messages exist (x is number of queues, delay is delay in seconds between each check)

Now, if you wish to minimize the amount of writes/reads with queues, consider buffering the requests from your web servers to queues so that not every data point is sent as an individual message, but batch a bunch together.  This will limit hits to queues that also count as transactions (both reads and writes).  You can use locks with static variables in your website that captures hits, so that everything is stored in memory and then flushed on a once-in-a-while basis to queues

If you wish to minimize amount of storage transactions against table storage, consider using local storage to pre-aggregate data if possible and only sync pre-aggregated data to                         table storage.  This may help

Whenever we're buffering data writes, the assumption is that it is possible to lose some data if the machine with the buffered data for some reason fails and the buffer has not yet been flushed.  Since we're not dealing with money transactions here, I'm assuming that your level of tolerance for data loss is somewhat slightly greater then 0 and the cost saving with buffering of writes offsets the potential rare data loss

HTH

Comment: I would also look at caching because is distributed and costs $1 per 10M transactions.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#header-8

Comment: Caching does not charge by transaction.  CDN is not the same thing and will not help here

Comment: If you do buffering in the web tier, you could reduce data loss by adding code in the OnStop() method to wait for outstanding HTTP requests to complete and flush pending transactions to storage. It still won't be 100% safe, but it'll be closer.

Comment: @Igorek, I was suggesting to use Caching for buffering before writing the whole chunk to table storage.

Comment: Thank you @Igorek for your great thoughts and suggestions! Glad you agree on the queue approach, i do a have couple of clarifying questions: 1) I was thinking of using Azure Storage Tables and not the Queues as I need to place these transactions there in a structured way (client_id, user_ip, date, etc.) - you agree? 2) I need to retain all of these transactions, is there harm to leave them in these queue tables or would you recommend a different approach?

Comment: Continuing my previous post... I know the Tables had 100T limit on space, but will performance be affected when there are billions of rows in there? Keep in mind that each transaction data for each row will be super small (couple of data points). Thanks!

Comment: I can't speak to the particular data structure as it is highly dependent on your business requirements, but I would try find ways to pre-aggregate them first. Also, definitely partition your tables by date, so that you can purge easily.  Deleting data from table storage is super hard, unless you delete full tables at a time